# F3PlotStrip dynamically added graph have issues

Tags: ios, graph

I'm currently working on a Graphs based iOS app. For this I'm using a third party control called [F3PlotStrip](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/f3plotstrip).

And implementation is something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _ecgView = [[F3PlotStrip alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 648, 299)];
    _ecgView.lineColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    _ecgView.lowerLimit = -10.0f;
    _ecgView.upperLimit = 10.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:_ecgView];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(testGraph:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)testGraph:(NSTimer *)a_timer
{
    _ecgView.value = 1.0;
}
```

But I got the result like:

[image: Code F3]

Then I added a `UIView` in my `xib` and changed its class to `F3PlotStrip` then connected it to the outlet as `_ecgView`.

Then I changed the code like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _ecgView.lineColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    _ecgView.lowerLimit = -10.0f;
    _ecgView.upperLimit = 10.0f;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(testGraph:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)testGraph:(NSTimer *)a_timer
{
    _ecgView.value = 1.0;
}
```

This time, I got the actual output:

[image: IB F3]

But why the issue is happening when I add the view through code? I can't depend on the second approach (Through IB) because I need to add graphs dynamically. Is there anyway to fix this issue? Or is this a bug of F3PlotStrip?

Answer (score 1):

I started using this widget this morning. I'm in bed on my iPhone now so cannot post what I want to post, but I will when I get into work in the morning.

I've managed to use it and do what you're trying to do with a dynamically added UIView, or should I say, F3PlotStrip.

I've also made the .h and the .m, ARC compliant too. Not sure if you'd done that.

I'll finish up tomorrow with some nice code that uses an NSTimer to read the contents of a NSArray to plot dynamically, with animation. Again with a View I've added to my viewcontroller as a subview.

Not looked in detail at your code as post what I've managed to get working, tomorrow.

Ok - here I am at work, sat in front of Xcode. Here's my VC that I've used as a basic testbed for this widget. I knocked it up quickly last night, but does the job. Initially, I'd added a UIView to my Storyboard first VC and subclassed it to F3PlotStrip. But, given I saw you you were having issues with dynamically adding the UIView, I thought I'd give it a go. The only difference between you're and mine is that I'm setting the UIView's frame after the alloc-init. See what you think. It uses a Sparkline approach as well as animating the graph on to the screen.

```
//
//  PlotViewController.m
//  PlotTest
//
//  Created by Carl Hine on 16/05/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Carl Hine. All rights reserved.
//

#define COLOUR_POWDER_BLUE                  [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:176/255.0f     green:224/255.0f blue:230/255.0f alpha:1]

#import "F3PlotStrip.h"
#import "PlotViewController.h"

@interface PlotViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet F3PlotStrip *IBOPLotView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *plotStipTimer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *plotData;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger plotDataArrayIdx;
@property (strong, nonatomic) F3PlotStrip *plotView2;

@end

@implementation PlotViewController

@synthesize plotStipTimer;
@synthesize plotData;
@synthesize plotDataArrayIdx;

BOOL bUsingDynPlot = YES;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)testGraph:(NSTimer *)a_timer {

    float RSEFigure = [[self.plotData objectAtIndex:plotDataArrayIdx] floatValue];

    if (bUsingDynPlot)
        _plotView2.value = RSEFigure;
    else
        _IBOPLotView.value = RSEFigure;

    ++plotDataArrayIdx;

    if (plotDataArrayIdx == [self.plotData count]) {
        [plotStipTimer invalidate];
        plotStipTimer = nil;
    }

}

- (void)configurePLotStrip:(F3PlotStrip *)plotStrip {

    plotDataArrayIdx = 0;
    // Random rubbish that makes it look like a heartbeat :
    self.plotData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:68.1f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:70.2f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:71.3f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:72.4f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:73.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:73.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:124.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:73.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:70.6f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:70.2f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:71.3f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:72.4f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:73.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:73.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:124.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:73.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:70.6f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:70.2f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:71.3f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:72.4f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:73.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:73.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:124.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:73.5f],
                 [NSNumber numberWithFloat:70.6f],
                 nil];

    // Get value bounds
    float max = -999999;
    float min = 999999;
    for (NSInteger i = 0;i <= self.plotData.count - 1;++i) {
        float RSEFigure = [[self.plotData objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
        if (RSEFigure > max)
            max = RSEFigure;
        if (RSEFigure < min)
            min = RSEFigure;
    }

    plotStrip.lowerLimit = min;
    plotStrip.upperLimit = max;
    plotStrip.lineColor = COLOUR_POWDER_BLUE;
    [self.view addSubview:_IBOPLotView];
    plotStipTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(testGraph:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    plotStrip.showDot = YES;
    plotStrip.capacity = self.plotData.count;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    if (bUsingDynPlot) {
        // Dynamically adding to view.
        _plotView2 = [[F3PlotStrip alloc] init];
        _plotView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        _plotView2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 293, 35);
        [[self view] addSubview:_plotView2];
        [self configurePLotStrip:_plotView2];
    } else {
        [self configurePLotStrip:_IBOPLotView];
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

@end
```

I hope this is easy enough for you to drop in to a new VC. Provided you have the F3PlotStrip.h and .m in your project folder, you'll be good to go - aside from adding a UIView to the VC.

Carl.

Comment: Why are you adding `[self.view addSubview:_IBOPLotView];` everytime in your `configurePLotStrip` method ?

Comment: Yes. It does seem a bit pointless. I essentially needed a Sparkline type plotter. I found the object on GitHub and googled to see if there were any problems. That's when I found this page. This chap couldn't add a PlotView programatically. Not so that it worked correctly anyhow. I'm not in front of my MAC, tapping away on my phone. But I guess the addSubview was A remnant line left in from the dynamic adding aspect.

Comment: Oooops. Apologies. You are that chap!!! Just noticed. Has any of it been any use to you? Glad to help, if it did.

Comment: Checked with your code, same issue occurs. Anyway thanks for helping :)